# filling Nan values based on conditions

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am dealing/handling missing values. I am using the titanic dataset and am trying to fill the missing values on the bases of the `Pclass` value.

Data set:

```
           Pclass   Age

             3      Nan
             3      23.0
             2      Nan
             1      21.0
             1      Nan
```

It might be a silly doubt but, in this block of code shown below. I am getting a warning for all 3 lines:

```
Data = pd.read_csv('train.csv')

Data.loc[Data.Pclass == 1][Data.Age.isnull()].fillna(38.0,inplace = True)
Data.loc[Data.Pclass == 2][Data.Age.isnull()].fillna(28.0,inplace = True)
Data.loc[Data.Pclass == 3][Data.Age.isnull()].fillna(22.0,inplace = True)
```

> UserWarning: Boolean Series key will be reindexed to match DataFrame index.

I want to produce the following result:

```
           Pclass   Age

             3      22.0
             3      23.0
             2      28.0
             1      21.0
             1      38.0
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do

```
Data.Age=Data.Age.fillna(Data.Pclass.map({1:38,2:28,3:22})
```